# Checkbox's state not properly shown when `performClick` is used

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I got a tricky problem here:

in my app, there's a list (using a ListView) and each item contains text and a checkbox aligned to the right hand side.
Now, clicking the checkbox itself works, I installed a handler (`OnClickListener`) for it and perform an internal action. The visible state of the checkbox is just as expected - clicked the first time the tick is there, clicked again the tick disappears.

Now I simply wanted to "extend" the clickable area to the complete list entry - my approach was to install an `OnItemClickListener` using `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` and within this listener I do the following:

```
resultView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkBox.performClick();
        }
    });
```

That sounds simple, but what happens is that sometimes (not every time) the tick in the checkbox does not appear after that! I added a `checkBox.invalidate()` but that did not help.

How can I have a checkbox "react" to the click of the complete list entry item???
Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the properties android:focusable and android:clickable to false for the checkbox? That will refer the clickevent to the parent of the checkbox, in this case your list item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use `performClick()` use `checkBox.setChecked( !checkBox.getChecked() );` instead. `performClick()` will cause the `onClickListener` to be called again potentially causing a recursion, which could explain the odd behaviour that you're seeing.

Comment: I tried doing this - but strangely this does not at all change the checkbox's state... plus: the action I need to perform is not done as the listener is not called at all. Should I call my listener manually?

Comment: Strange: if I do both, first setChecked() and then performClick() and set break points, setChecked does NOT call the onClickListener (as expected) but performClick does - BIG BUT: the check state is not correct! Setting it to true with setChecked and debugging into the listener called by performClick, the state is still false! Why?

Comment: Thinking further about this, there can be some strange behaviours when changing state in the `ListView onItemClickListener`whch I believe are because there is processing done after your code has completed. ISTR that I had to implement my own Adapter, use stable IDs in that Adapter, add an `onClickListener` to the checkbox in each view in `onCreateView`, and set the checked state of the checkbox in `onCreateView` according to whether the item's stable id was contained in `getCheckedItemIds` from the ListView.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your advice! I redesigned my whole set up, the checkboxes are now only to show the state, they are not clickable nor focusable any more - all actions are taken in the onItemClickListener. That works. I got screwed because of the complex things going on when you got two listeners!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
//        pi = (PackageInfo) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        cb.performClick();
        if (cb.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue.add(tv.getText().toString());
        } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
            checkedValue.remove(tv.getText().toString());
        }
    }
```